# Do I need foregin keys to reference tables to each other

Tags: sql, database

When using foriegn keys, I am not sure if I am suppose to use foriegn keys in two tables where it contains the same field. For example:

Option Table:

```
OptionId (PK auto)  OptionType
1                   A-C 
2                   A-D
3                   A-E
```

Question Table:

```
QuestionId (PK auto)  Question  OptionId (FK Option)
1                      2+2       2
2                      3+3       1
```

I make the OptionId in the Question Table a foreign key but am I suppose to make the OptionId in the Option Table a foreign key as well referencing to the Question Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

A foreign key is a constraint: it is intended to insure database integrity.  You wouldn't want someone to be able to delete an Option that a Question is joined to, as that question would no longer be valid.  However, it would make perfect sense to delete a Question even though the Option it was joined to still exists -- that Option may well apply to other existing or future questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer :) So never make a field in the parent table a foriegn key to match the same field in a child table. Thanks

Comment: Well, never is a strong word.  Sometimes the dependency could go both ways, if the relationship is one-to-one, but then you wouldn't really have a parent and a child.  And you could imagine wanting constraints in the other direction -- e.g. you can't have an invoice without at least one invoice_row -- but you wouldn't use a foreign key to enforce that.